# Not able to access dataframe column after groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

```
import pandas as pd

df_prices = pd.read_csv('data/prices.csv', delimiter = ',')


# sample data from prices.csv 
# date,symbol,open,close,low,high,volume
# 2010-01-04,PCLN,222.320007,223.960007,221.580002,225.300003,863200.0
# 2010-01-04,PDCO,29.459999,28.809999,28.65,29.459999,1519900.0
# 2010-01-04,PEG,33.139999,33.630001,32.889999,33.639999,5130400.0
# 2010-01-04,PEP,61.189999,61.240002,60.639999,61.52,6585900.0
# 2010-01-04,PFE,18.27,18.93,18.24,18.940001,52086000.0
# 2010-01-04,PFG,24.110001,25.0,24.1,25.030001,3470900.0
# 2010-01-04,PG,61.110001,61.119999,60.630001,61.310001,9190800.0


df_latest_prices = df_prices.groupby('symbol').last()

df_latest_prices.iloc[115]

# date      2014-02-07
# open           54.26
# close          55.28
# low            53.63
# high           55.45
# volume    3.8587e+06
# Name: CTXS, dtype: object

df_latest_prices.iloc[115].volume

# 3858700.0

df_latest_prices.iloc[115].Name

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
# <ipython-input-8-6385f0b6e014> in <module>
# ----> 1 df_latest_prices.iloc[115].Name
```

I have a dataframe called 'df_latest_prices' which was obtained by doing a groupby on another dataframe.
I am able to access the columns of df_latest_prices as shown above, but I am not able to the access the column that was used in the groupby column (ie. 'symbol')

What do I do to get the 'symbol' from a particular row of this Dataframe ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `name` attribute:

```
df_latest_prices.iloc[115].name
```

**Sample**:

```
s = pd.Series([1,2,3], name='CTXS')

print (s.name)
CTXS
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you problem is two fold, first you are using 'Name' instead of 'name' as @jezrael points out, secondly, when use .iloc with single brackets, [] and a single integer position, you are returning the scalar value at that location.

To fix this, I'd use double brackets to return a slice of the pd.Series or pd.Dataframe.

Using jezrael's setup.

```
s = pd.Series([1,2,3], name='CTXS')
s.iloc[[1]].name
```

Output:

```
'CTXS'
```

Note:

```
type(s.iloc[1])
```

Returns

```
numpy.int64
```

Where as,

```
type(s.iloc[[1]])
```

Returns

```
pandas.core.series.Series
```

which has the 'name' attribute